# routes not directing in laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am surprised this is not working but maybe I am missing something...I am trying to access from the main page (index.php) either the login page or the signup page. I created both routes to be handled. When I click on the link, it goes to another page such as /website/login and shows not found. Here is the routes.php code:

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');

Route::get('login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'MembersController@loadLoginView'));

Route::get('signup', array('as' => 'signup', 'uses' => 'MembersController@loadRegisterView'));
```

MembersController code:

```
<?php

class MembersController extends BaseController {

    public function loadRegisterView()
    {
        return View::make('members.register');
    }

    public function loadLoginView()
    {
        return View::make('members.login');
    }
}
```

and inside views I have a folder called members and inside it I got login.blade.php and register.blade.php.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: View `signup.blade.php` should be named `register.blade.php`. Otherwise you'll be trying to render a non-existent view.

Comment: Sorry that was actually a typo in the question. It is called register.blade.php. Thanks for noticing

Comment: Do you have an .htaccess? if you go to http://www.example.com/index.php/login does it work?

Comment: @DamienPirsy yup that worked! How can I remove the index.php from the url though?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the index.php you could use the .htaccess provided on the Laravel website:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Be sure you're running on an Apache server with Mod_rewrite active. I'm not expert on other servers, so I can't suggest you alternative. On Laravel's website there's this snippet for Nginx:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Have no idea on IIS server, though.

Otherwise, you'll need to keep the 'index.php' in the url, like http://www.example.com/index.php/login

Comment: I am using MAMP...any change you know how to make sure mod_rewrite is active?